# How to read a specific amount of characters from a text file

Tags: c++, string, file, char

I tried to do it like this

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char b[2];
    ifstream f("prad.txt");
    f>>b ;
    cout <<b;
    return 0;
}
```

It should read 2 characters but it reads whole line. This worked on another language but doesn't work in C++ for some reason.

Comment: +1 and "Thank you" for providing a short, complete sample program. http://sscce.org

Comment: "This worked on another language but doesn't work in C++ for some reason." This is one of the worst assumptions you can make in programming. They are two different languages, so they can have different behaviour.

Comment: Yeah, it's pretty dangerous to go around thinking that. If you're coming to C++ from Java (which is what it looks like from your mistake) you really do need to sit down with some reading on pointers and arrays and make sure you get what's going on before you shoot yourself in the foot.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use [`read()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/read) to specify the number of characters to read:

```
char b[3] = "";
ifstream f("prad.txt");

f.read(b, sizeof(b) - 1); // Read one less that sizeof(b) to ensure null
cout << b;                // terminated for use with cout.
```

Comment: In order to make the relation between `3` and `2` a bit more evident, I would advise to use a named constant. `size_t const BufferSize = 2;`, `char b[BufferSize+1] = "";` and `f.read(b, BufferSize);`

Comment: @MatthieuM., I would normally use `sizeof(b) - 1` (if possible). Code updated.

Comment: I am always reluctant to recommend this, because if `b` is a pointer the compilation still works by you get a fixed `7` on 64 bits platforms. You could use a `size` function for arrays though, with templates it's easy.

Comment: @MatthieuM. good point. Have seen solution using templates (many times on this site) but the purpose here was to indicate the requirement for null termination.

Answer (score 2):

> This worked on another language but doesn't work in C++ for some
>   reason.

Some things change from language to language. In particular, in this case you've run afoul of the fact that in C++ pointers and arrays are scarcely different. That array gets passed to operator>> as a pointer to char, which is interpreted as a string pointer, so it does what it does to char buffers (to wit read until the width limit or end of line, whichever comes first). Your program *ought* to be crashing when that happens, since you're overflowing your buffer.

Answer (score 0):

```
istream& get (char* s, streamsize n );
```

> Extracts characters from the stream and stores them as a c-string into
>   the array beginning at s. Characters are extracted until either (n -
>   1) characters have been extracted or the delimiting character '\n' is
>   found. The extraction also stops if the end of file is reached in the
>   input sequence or if an error occurs during the input operation. If
>   the delimiting character is found, it is not extracted from the input
>   sequence and remains as the next character to be extracted. Use
>   getline if you want this character to be extracted (and discarded).
>   The ending null character that signals the end of a c-string is
>   automatically appended at the end of the content stored in s.