# Reading a fixed number of characters in a line C++

Tags: c++

This is a pretty basic question as I've just started in C++. I am to read 20 characters of a line from a file (text). Example:

```
Wayne, Bruce        0000000
```

I would want to save "Wayne, Bruce" and the spaces following it into a string. I've been trying for a while and I can't figure out how to go about this. As such, if anybody could help me out, I ask that the answer is kept simple. I tried googling this and think I found some answers, but most of them were way over my head. Thank you.

Comment: possible duplicate of [C++ How to read specific amount of characters from a text file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9518659/c-how-to-read-specific-amount-of-characters-from-a-text-file)

Comment: I think you will find that the answer given on the previous link is "simple". Give it a shot!

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string str;
    std::ifstream file("test.txt");

    std::copy_n(
        std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(file),
        20,
        std::back_inserter(str)
    );
}
```

Note that this isn't safe if the file in question has less than 20 chars.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read in chunks of 20 characters from a file then you can try something like this,

```
void readFromFile(char *input)  //Parameter is your filename
{
  ifstream file_input;
  file_input.open(input, ios::in);
  vector<string> vec;         // Optional in case you want to store these
   while (file_input.good()) {
    char arr[21] = "";
    file_input.read (arr,20);
    vec.push_back(arr);        //if you want to store these chunks into vector
 }
 file_input.close();
}
```