# Why my program doesn't print a specific number of characters from a text file? (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, file, char, buffer

I tried to write a program (also posted its code below) that reads a text file and prints out a specific number of characters (from the begining of a file). A function called **checkFile** is taking two parameters (one to pass the title of the file and a second for the number of characters to print). The function contains exceptions handling, one of the exceptions is printing out a message when the number of characters we choose to print from the file, exceeds the number of characters that the file contains. The program is running with no errors or warnings but i don't get the result that i want...For some reason the characters do not print on the screen. I noticed though that if i don't initialize the buffer, the program prints out some garbage characters.

Just for the record i found this [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9518659/how-to-read-a-specific-amount-of-characters-from-a-text-file) thread(question) that helped me complete the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void checkFile(const char *myFile, int a)
{
    char buffer[a] = {'\0'};

    int counter = 0; //amount of characters of the file
    string line = "" ;

    ifstream inFile(myFile);

    try
    {
        if(inFile.good())
        {
            while (!inFile.eof()) //Counts the characters of the file until eof is true
            {
                getline(inFile, line); //It stores a line from the file in the "line" string
                cout << line << endl; //Print each line of the file - checking the code
                counter = counter + line.length();
                cout << counter << endl; // print the number of characters of the file
            }

             if (a <= counter)
             {
                inFile.read(buffer, sizeof(buffer)); //load the buffer with the first "a" characters of the file
                for(int i = 0 ; i < a; i++)
                {
                    cout << buffer[i];
                }
            }
            else if (a > counter) throw 101;
        } else if (!inFile.is_open())throw 99.0;
    }catch(float x) {
        cout << "\nThere is problem with the file! ERROR: " << x << endl;
    } catch(int y) {
        cout << "\nNot enough characters in the file! ERROR: " << y << endl;
    }

    inFile.close();
}

int main()
{
    checkFile("text.txt", 6); //checkFile("name_of_file", amount_of_chars)

    return 0;
}
```

Assuming there is a file named "text.txt" and contains the phrase:

> Hello! What a wonderful day!

with the call of the function `checkFile("text.txt", 6); the program should print only the part

> Hello!

Note down that the phrase is 28 characters long (with the spaces) if i ask for 29 or higher the program catches the exception ERROR 101.

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: `char buffer[a] = {'\0'};` is g++ language extension (a C99 Variable Length Array). Use a `std::vector` for standard code.

Comment: Don't do `while (!inFile.eof())` ever. Check `.fail()` for a loop condition.

Comment: `getline(inFile, line)` doesn't check for failure.

Comment: `inFile.read(buffer, sizeof(buffer));` is attempted right after you have established `eof` condition.

Comment: Tip: you can use a free tool such as AStyle (artistic style) to **fix the formatting** of your code. Best do that before posting question.

Comment: What Alf says: You use `getline` in a loop until there is nothing left in the file. Then `read` will find nothing, as `getline` has already consumed everything. Why not skip all this and just do `inFile.read(buffer, a);` to request `a` characters, and then check with [`inFile.gcount()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/gcount) how many you got.

Comment: Thanks for helping and taking the time to comment! From your comments i understand that i don't know many things...i tried inFile.gcount() after inFile.read(buffer, a) and it worked perfectly...

Comment: I will also try to use std::vector...I fill though that there are many ways to accomplish this program, but i don't know any...do you have any suggestions? Or maybe to what direction i sould follow to find the simplest and most steady way?